# Error while using selenium : SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: The version of ChromeDriver supports chrome version 114 not 119

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run the code, however there seems to be an issue with the driver version. I've used autoinstaller to update the driver version however this issue has popped up. This issue randomly came to fruition, as it wasn't really apparent maybe a few hours ago. There has been no change in code since then.

```
!pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller


import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller

# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
service = Service()
# set path to chromedriver as per your configuration
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

# set the target URL
url = "put-url-here-to-scrape"

# set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=service)
```

this is the code

Answer (score 0):

```
Error while using selenium : SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: The version of ChromeDriver supports chrome version 114 not 119
```

Above exception occurs when your code is using version `114` ChromeDriver, and the Chrome browser in your system is version `119`.

**Suggestion:** I don't know what version of selenium do you use. If you are on latest selenium version(`v4.6.0` or higher), you can utilise selenium's built-in tool [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) to download and manage the drivers.

In other words, `Selenium Manager` will do exactly what `chromedriver-autoinstaller` is intended to do. So when there is a built-in solution to achieve it, why again use a third party tool?

Refer the code below. In the below code, selenium will detect the browser in your system and downloads and uses the matching browser driver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

# setup chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') # ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
service = Service()

# set the target URL
url = "https://www.google.com/"

# set up the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=service)
driver.get(url)
```